# How to display a file name as a caption for images in a gridview

Tags: java, android, textview, imageview, caption

I am developing an android app right now and I have the images from my res/drawable-mdpi folder being displayed in a gridview. I also have captions being displayed on the bottom of the images right now, which are preset words which I have in a String[]text. Instead of having these preset words being displayed, what lines of code can I use to display the filename of the image being displayed (I want the app itself to find the name of the file and display it, instead of me having to manually type in the file names). For example, if I have a blue box being displayed and the image file name is blue_0.jpg how can I make the caption say "blue_0.jpg"? Thanks!

Comment: String[] text can contain the name of images from "blue_0.jpg" its a string ryt?? didnt get your exact problm??

Comment: I want the app to find the name of the file for itself, without me having to manually type in file names to be displayed.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [getResourceEntryName](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html#getResourceEntryName%28int%29) of the Resource class.